# Copying array in $http.post method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.openDocImg = function(id, e){
    var data = [];

    ...

    $http.post("/showDocument", cid).then(function(response){
        data = response.data.slice(0);
        console.log(data);
    });

    console.log(data.length);  //displays 0
    console.log(data);

    ...
}
```

I don't get it completely why the data in the post method is filled with content and the outside isn't. Is it because of the variable scope inside and outside the function?

And how do I copy the content to the outer scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$http.post` method is executed *asynchronous*,  `console.log(data.length);` statement is executed before you're receiving response from server.

So that's why you're receiving `0` when you're trying to log the length of `data`.

You should use a `callback` function.

```
function postRequest(callback){
  $http.post("/showDocument", cid).then(function(response){
    callback(response.data.slice(0));
  });
}

$scope.openDocImg = function(id, e){
    var data = [];

    ...

    postRequest(function(data){
       console.log(data.length); 
       console.log(data);
    });

    ...
}
```

Comment: So there's no way to copy it directly to the outer scope and I should work inside the postRequest function?

Comment: @temp, no, you have to use callback like in my answer or promises.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I'll try this out.